# testing google backend engine on phone

Tags: android

I have an existing android app to which I plan to add Google cloud engine backend. I am following the steps as here 
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae. 
I used the option "Google-->generate app engine backend" by right clicking on my existing project. and then went forward to test this.

I started the devapp server( I can see it running at localost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore). However When I run my application, I don't see the device registered in the 127.0.0.1:8888. The application runs as it used to run before. I tried both on emulator and on phone but the application just runs as before but I don't see any device registered in my devappserver.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic steps for application registration were missing in my application. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
Adding them now and that should solve the problem.